# DatabaseLocked exception even after closing with db.close() and db.setTransactionSuccessful()

Tags: android, sqlite

The application am working on will initially have one database with a table, say `tbl_usr` which will have only one record. Basically we are trying to keep *one user per device*. When the user logs in from the device with an **auth code**, his details will be fetched from server and stored in database. Next time if he tries to enter different **auth code**, which is valid but is not in table then he will not be allowed to proceed. Below is a common `DBHelper` class.

But whatever approach am trying, I am getting **databaselocked** exception, when tried for the 2nd time login. I've referred various links where in it was suggested to use different instance of `database` within method, but still it comes with error. Below is my Helper class

```
public class DBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String CREATE_TABLE;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="IPDB";
    private static String UserMessage="";
    private int tableType=0;

    private ContentValues cValues;

    private Cursor cursor;
    public enum TableTypes{
        Table1
    };

    public DBaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath()+"/"+DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        TableTypes tableTypes=TableTypes.values()[tableType];
        switch (tableTypes){
            case Table1:
                CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_usr....";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.close();
        System.out
                .println("onCreate Method Done.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        /*db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+LOGIN_TABLE);*/
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /*this is the method which gets called from other class Like*/ 
    /*helper.insertRecord(tableParams);*/

    public HashMap<String,String> insertRecord(HashMap<String,String> dbaseParams){
        HashMap<String,String> response=new HashMap<String,String>();
        tableType=Integer.parseInt(dbaseParams.get("tableType"));
        cValues = new ContentValues();
        String TableName="";
        TableTypes tableTypes=TableTypes.values()[tableType];
        switch (tableTypes){
            case Table1:
                String AuthCode=dbParams.get("AuthCode");
                /*if user exists then check if its the same user*/
                if( CheckUserRecordExists(AuthCode) && empty(UserMessage) ){
                    response.put("isSuccess","true");
                    return response;
                }
                else {
                    if (!empty(UserMessage)) {
                        response.put("isSuccess", "false");
                        response.put("message",UserMessage);
                        return response;
                    }
                    /*add new user
                    Fill cValues declared above*/
                    TableName = "Table1";
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        SQLiteDatabase dataBase = getWritableDatabase();
        /*insert data into database*/
        try {
           dataBase.beginTransaction();
           long rowID = dataBase.insertOrThrow(TableName, null, cValues);
           dataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            dataBase.close();
        }
        response.put("isSuccess", "true");
        return response;
    }

    private boolean CheckUserRecordExists(String authCode){
        UserMessage="";

        SQLiteDatabase dataBase=getReadableDatabase();
        /*Exception here when comes for 2nd time after new installation*/

        cursor = dataBase.query("Table1", new String[]{"COUNT(*)"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int iCount=cursor.getInt(0);
        /*check if any record exist*/
        if(iCount>0){
            dataBase.close();
            if(!cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();
            /*check if the code entered matches with the record existing*/
            if(!CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot("Table1","Auth_Code",authCode))
            {
                UserMessage="Invalid login!";
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
        else{
            dataBase.close();
            if(!cursor.isClosed()) cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot( String TableName,
                                                      String dbfield, String fieldValue) {
        /*checking if user is same user*/
        SQLiteDatabase dataBase=getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = { dbfield };
        String selection = dbfield + " =?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { fieldValue };
        String limit = "1";

        Cursor cursor = dataBase.query(TableName, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, limit);
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        cursor.close();
        dataBase.close();
        return exists;
    }
    public static boolean empty( final String s ) {
        return s == null || s.trim().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

I know its a huge code, but logic is simple. But the problem is database lock. Could someone let me know how I can make sure that database is always in valid state on each operation?

Comment: Got the same problem. I guess the cause is of "overlapping" Database operations. I deleted every close call and just put a method that checks first if db==null and as second, if not null, db.isOpen() . If null, create a new, if open, I close the database and open it again. I set this method on every call that effects the database...but this depends on your needs.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs how would you close a database separately in a method when you are getting it declared internally?

Comment: I don´t understand your question I believe....do you mean, how to close the database in a separated class? I don´t, I do every call of this method inside the SQLiteHelper class..

Comment: For example, in your `insertRecord()` method, as first put this method and then start your operation. And so, I do it in every method...I could give a an example, but this is maybe not the best solution and not made for an answer...

Comment: Bouncing over my head.. Could you provide some example on what you are doing? What kind of method and is it withing same dbhelper class? Are you passing instance of database into the method where you are checking for `null` and `db.isOpen()`?

Comment: ok, sorry, now I got ya...could I sent you an email to your account showed in your profile?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yes please.. You can..

Comment: ha....:) or you are doing it like Iaalto answered ....if it doesn´t help, give some time to write....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs.. It did not help buddy.. Yea.. you can take your time.. :)

Comment: @Opiatefuchs.. All is well.. works good now after laalto's answer.. :) Thanks much for your time.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `beginTransaction()` but no matching calls to `endTransaction()`. An ongoing transaction keeps the database in a locked state and also keeps the internal reference count nonzero, so `close()` does not yet actually close the database.

The conventional pattern for transactional operations is

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // db operations that can throw

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

---

Also in your `onCreate()` you should not be closing the database since you don't own it.

Comment: No buddy..  It still remains the same.. The problem occurs within `CheckUserRecordExists` method.. I am not getting from where the `db` is getting open...

Comment: Yes didn't read all of your code. Just pointing out one source of database locking; there can be others.

Comment: I corrected that part of code as per your suggestion.. :)

Comment: is `db.close()` needed within finally along with `db.endTransaction();`? If yes should it come before or after `db.endTransaction();`?

Comment: `db.close()` comes last after all other database operations are done. But closing your database is not strictly necessary and omitting it does not cause database locking.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @laalto.. Couldn't just thank you enough.. Both suggestions were needed.. :) Looks good now.. :) Also, you said `db.close()` is not needed.. so this won't cause any problem right?

Comment: Omitting `db.close()` prevents GC from cleaning up your potentially unused database-related objects. They consume resources such as memory and file descriptors so it's up to your app's performance requirements how strict you need to be about releasing those references.

Comment: Cool.. Thank you so much for your help once again.. :) Much Appreciated.. :)